# Mongo + PHP: Updating Documents in a collection with a new Array

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to add new arrays to existing documents in a collection:

```
    $lat = '38.9586307';
    $lon = '-77.3570028';
    $location = 'office';

    $latLong = array($lat,$lon);

    $newdata = array('$set' => array('latLong' => $latLong));

    $collection->update(array('location' => $location), $newdata);
```

But it is not working...am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add to your question dump of that document before and after executing this code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to add a "multiple" document update condition to the end of the update command:

```
$collection->update(array('location' => $location), $newdata, array("multiple" => true));
```

Comment: You did not mention you have multiple documents :) Glad you found a solution anyway.